# Access Database Automatically sorting records! How to stop?

Tags: database, vb.net, sorting, ms-access

i am building a program that uses a database.

When i enter my data into the database it doesnt stay as entered. It is automatically sorted into ascending order by a field that contains the ID number. The problem is when i create a new record programatically, it creates a record in another table with the same row number.

I need to stop access automatically sorting the records. any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  If you want someone to take time out of their busy day to help you, please spend a little time crafting a usable question.  See these links - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask  and http://sscce.org/  You show no code or anything of value to help answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

A relational database does not have the concept of an order of records per se; instead retrieved records are ordered by the query used to retrieve them - either in your code, or behind the scenes in the Access gui. So if you want them to appear in a specific order, then write a query including an ORDER BY clause to suit.

Answer (score 1):

Like in all relational databases, the rows in MS Access don't have a fixed order.

If you select data from a table without specifying a `ORDER BY` clause in your query, the database will return the rows in random order.
Often the order will look sensible *(like in your case, ordered ascending by the `ID` column)*, and if you run the same query several times, the order might really be the same.

But there's no guarantee - you can't rely on this order, you have to specify one yourself by ordering by the `ID` column or any other column.

---

I think that your problem *(besides apparently not knowing how ordering works in a relational database)* is this:

> The problem is when i create a new record programatically, it creates a record in another table with the same row number.

If I'm understanding you correctly:
When you need the record in the other table to have the same value, just take the value from the `ID` column after inserting into the first table (given that `ID` is the primary key) and use that value to save the data into the second table.

Answer (score 0):

Removing any indexing from the table is the easy way. But then you have no index.

I would just create a new field in your table called "PretendRowNumber" and insert the would be row number into it. Then you can at least tie your two tables back to each other.